# How can I increase performance Python script using numpy and numba?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, vectorization, numba

How can I increase performance Python script using numpy and numba?

I’m trying to convert decimal number to 21-number system.

Input: [15, 18, 28, 11, 7, 5, 41, 139, 6, 507]

Output: [[15], [18], [1, 7], [11], [7], [5], [1, 20], [6, 13], [6], [1, 3, 3]]

My script is working well using CPU.

How can I modify my script? I want to increase performance using GPU.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize
import numba as nb

elements = [
    "n|0",
    "n|1",
    "n|2",
    "n|3",
    "n|4",
    "n|5",
    "n|6",
    "n|7",
    "n|8",
    "n|9",
    "n|10",

    "o|+",
    "o|*",
    "o|/",
    "om|-",

    "bl|(",
    "br|)",

    "e|**2",
    "e|**3",
    "e|**0.5",
    "e|**(1/3)",
]

elements_len = len(elements)

def decimal_to_custom(number):
    x = (number % elements_len)
    ch = [x]
    if (number - x != 0):
        return decimal_to_custom(number // elements_len) + ch
    else:
        return ch

decimal_numbers = np.array([15, 18, 28, 11, 7, 5, 41, 139, 6, 507]) #very big array
custom_numers = []
for decimal_number in decimal_numbers:
    custom_numer = decimal_to_custom(decimal_number)
    custom_numers.append(custom_numer)

print(custom_numers)
```

Comment: One speed-up would be to use *divmod* instead of your conversion function.  If `l = [15, 18, 28, 11, 7, 5, 41, 139, 6, 507]` then you can convert using `[divmod(i,21) for i in l]` which will give you a list of tuples.

Comment: What makes you think that running this on the GPU would be any faster?

Comment: @norok2 GPU is nearly a 100x faster than CPU https://weeraman.com/put-that-gpu-to-good-use-with-python-e5a437168c01

Comment: Do you realize that there are assumptions with that statement that are not necessarily fulfilled with your problem? If everything could be made faster by running into the GPU, why bothering manufacturing CPUs in the first place.

Comment: I am unsure we need to know what is in `elements`. I think it is more relevant to know whether you do need the result to be a `list` or you can use a NumPy array **and** you know the largest value in `decimal_numbers`.

Comment: @Ikenitenine No. Please read the article more carefully. The article do not states that: the x100 is the speed up from an inefficient sequential implementation to a parallel one using the GPU. In fact, the benchmark is even biased since it do not consider page faults and assume the array is physically filled with zeros before the computation which is not the case on mainstream platforms. Doing multiple runs would have mitigated this big bias but this has not been done (even though this is the basics). GPUs will never give you such a speed-up if you compare *optimized* codes *properly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be summarized as:

```py
import numpy as np


def decimal_to_custom(number, k):
    x = (number % k)
    ch = [x]
    if (number - x != 0):
        return decimal_to_custom(number // k, k) + ch
    else:
        return ch


def remainders_OP(arr, k):    
    result = []
    for value in arr:
        result.append(decimal_to_custom(value, k))
    return result


decimal_numbers = np.array([15, 18, 28, 11, 7, 5, 41, 139, 6, 507]) #very big array
print(remainders_OP(decimal_numbers, elements_len))
# [[15], [18], [1, 7], [11], [7], [5], [1, 20], [6, 13], [6], [1, 3, 3]]
```

This code can be speed-up already by replacing the costly recursive implementation of `decimal_to_custom()` with an iterative and simpler version `mod_list()` which appends and revert rather than the *very* expensive head insert (equivalent to `list.insert(0, x)`) that is implemented in OP:

```py
def mod_list(x, k):
    result = []
    while x >= k:
        result.append(x % k)
        x //= k
    result.append(x)
    return result[::-1]


def remainders(arr, k):
    result = []
    for x in arr:
        result.append(mod_list(x, k))
    return result


print(remainders(decimal_numbers, elements_len))
# [[15], [18], [1, 7], [11], [7], [5], [1, 20], [6, 13], [6], [1, 3, 3]]
```

Now, both can be accelerated with Numba, to obtain some speed-up:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def mod_list_nb(x, k):
    result = []
    while x >= k:
        result.append(x % k)
        x //= k
    result.append(x)
    return result[::-1]


@nb.njit
def remainders_nb(arr, k):
    result = []
    for x in arr:
        result.append(mod_list_nb(x, k))
    return result


print(remainders_nb(decimal_numbers, elements_len))
# [[15], [18], [1, 7], [11], [7], [5], [1, 20], [6, 13], [6], [1, 3, 3]]
```

A number of options can be passed on to the decorator, including `target_backend="cuda"` to have the computation to run on the GPU.
As we shall see with the benchmarks, it is not going to be beneficial.
The reason is that `list.append()` (as well as `list.insert()`) is not easy to run in parallel, and hence you cannot easily exploit the massive parallelism of GPUs!

Anyway, the above solutions are slowed down by the choice of the underlying data container.

If one uses fixed size arrays instead of dynamically growing a `list` at each iteration, this is going to result in a much faster execution:

```py
def remainders_fixed_np(arr, k, m):
    arr = arr.copy()
    n = len(arr)
    result = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.int_)
    for i in range(m - 1, -1, -1):
        result[:, i] = arr[:, i + 1] % k
        arr //= k
    return result


print(remainders_fixed_np(decimal_numbers, elements_len, 3).T)
# [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
#  [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  6  0  3]
#  [15 18  7 11  7  5 20 13  6  3]]
```

or, with Numba acceleration (and avoiding unnecessary computation):

```py
@nb.njit
def remainders_fixed_nb(arr, k, m):
    n = len(arr)
    result = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int_)
    for i in range(n):
        j = m - 1
        x = arr[i]
        while x >= k:
            q, r = divmod(x, k)
            result[i, j] = r
            x = q
            j -= 1
        result[i, j] = x
    return result


print(remainders_fixed_nb(decimal_numbers, elements_len, 3).T)
# [[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
#  [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  6  0  3]
#  [15 18  7 11  7  5 20 13  6  3]]
```

---

## Some Benchmarks

Now some benchmarks run on Google Colab show some indicative timings, where:

- the `_nb` ending indicates Numba acceleration
- the `_pnb` ending indicates Numba acceleration with `parallel=True` and the outermost `range()` replaced with `nb.prange()`
- the `_cunb` ending indicates Numba acceleration with target CUDA `target_backend="cuda"`
- the `_cupnb` is Numba acceleration with both parallelization and target CUDA

```
m = 4
n = 100000
arr = np.random.randint(1, k ** m - 1, n)

funcs = remainders_OP, remainders, remainders_nb, remainders_cunb
base = funcs[0](arr, k)
for func in funcs:
    res = func(arr, k)
    is_good = base == res
    print(f"{func.__name__:>16s}  {is_good!s:>5s}  ", end="")
    %timeit -n 4 -r 4 func(arr, k)
#    remainders_OP   True  333 ms ± 4.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
#       remainders   True  268 ms ± 5.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
#    remainders_nb   True  46.9 ms ± 3.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
#  remainders_cunb   True  46.4 ms ± 1.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)


fixed_funcs = remainders_fixed_np, remainders_fixed_nb, remainders_fixed_pnb, remainders_fixed_cunb, remainders_fixed_cupnb
base = fixed_funcs[0](arr, k, m)
for func in fixed_funcs:
    res = func(arr, k, m)
    is_good = np.all(base == res)
    print(f"{func.__name__:>24s}  {is_good!s:>5s}  ", end="")
    %timeit -n 8 -r 8 func(arr, k, m)
#      remainders_fixed_np   True  10 ms ± 2.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 8 runs, 8 loops each)
#      remainders_fixed_nb   True  3.6 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 8 runs, 8 loops each)
#     remainders_fixed_pnb   True  2.68 ms ± 550 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 8 runs, 8 loops each)
#    remainders_fixed_cunb   True  3.49 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 8 runs, 8 loops each)
#   remainders_fixed_cupnb   True  2.63 ms ± 314 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 8 runs, 8 loops each)
```

This indicate that running on the GPU has minimal effect.
The greatest speed-up is obtained by changing the data container to a pre-allocated one.
The Numba acceleration provides some acceleration both with the dynamic allocation and with the pre-allocated versions.